# Understanding DHCPv6 Stateful Solicit message

Tags: dhcp, ipv6

I have been reading the full `RFC 3315` and trying to generated spoofed nodes to ask for  IPv6 address.  (only for practice)

Right now, I have a Ubuntu with wide-dhcpv6-server (the DHCPv6 server), one Cisco 2811 router with the DHCPv6 relay agent avaliable and two nodes, one with wide-dhcpv6-client (a dhcp client program ) and the one trying to generate the first message.

The node with the wide-dhcpv6-client  generate his Solicit message and the Router relay take the message and pass it to the server ( which it's on other subnet) , and the full process  take place ( Solicit, adverstiment,  Request and reply).

The second node, generates  spoofed  Solicit messages, with the MAC addres on DELL OUI's. I'm only trying to replicate the process for a new one node on the network. I'm trying to obtain the  Adverstiment message from the server.

Until this moment this is the  message generated (and captured using Wireshark) by the valid client:

```
fe80::221:70ff:fe1c:9b79    ff02::1:2   DHCPv6  112 Solicit XID: 0xfc828 CID: 0001000119c50e640021701c9b79
```

And this is the one by the spoofed node:

```
fe80::26b6:fdff:fee5:d276   ff02::1:2   DHCPv6  112 Solicit XID: 0x15341f CID: 0001000119c6616e24b6fde5d276
```

The message created by the node with the wide-dhcpv6-client program and the spoofed seem to be equal on almost everything except DUID,  Link-layer Address and Transaction-ID but that is correct (the first two are for identify the node on the future and the second on the solicit message should be 100% random but will be the base for the other 3 messages )

Any idea where  I could try to search for any clue?

P.S. I already tried to switch the DHCPv6 server to the same subnet and remove the relay agent.

Comment: ... Ok...  writing my problem helped me... I think so I find my  lethal and basic error...   The spoofed node don't exist , the second message (the server adverstiment )  is unicast, that means BEFORE sending the message there is a NDP Neighbor Solicitation which never got answer and for the same reason  the relay agent (or the server when is on the same sub-net)  NEVER send the second message...  DAH!!! Now I need find a good table to hit my head (or rest until tomorrow for trying again with a valid host)

Comment: you can answer you own question, you don't have to write a comment :)

Answer (score 1):

The spoofed node don't exist , the second message (the server adverstiment ) is unicast, that means BEFORE sending the message there is a NDP Neighbor Solicitation which never got answer and for the same reason the relay agent (or the server when is on the same sub-net) NEVER send the second message.

That mean if you want to spoof  IPv6 hosts you need to be ready to answer NDP messages too (or don't do it).

Comment: Your question is still listed as unsolved. Did this solve the problem? If so, please click the tickbox so that it turns green, to indicate that it is solved.